# awk not making substitutions in last column of csv

Tags: bash, macos, csv, awk, line-endings

I need to work across the columns of a large `.tsv` and replace the column name if it matches any of a number of strings, labelling it an error if no match is found. Below is a simplified version of what I have, and it works here.

Sample tab-separated input `test.tsv`:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
A   B   C   Foo
D   E   F   Bar
G   H   I   Baz
```

Script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -eu
shopt -s failglob

awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} \
     {if (NR==1) \
        {for (i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++) \
        if ($i == "Col1") { $i = "NewCol1" } \
        else if ( $i == "Col2") { $i = "NewCol2" } \
        else if ( $i == "Col4") { $i = "NewCol4" } \
        else { $i = "Error: "$i } \
        } print \
        }' test.tsv
```

Tab-separated output:

```
NewCol1 NewCol2 Error: Col3 NewCol4
A   B   C   Foo
D   E   F   Bar
G   H   I   Baz
```

However, in my real process `Col4` is not being successfully processed. Instead, it is being flagged as an error. The issue does not occur if I use LibreOffice Calc to open the file and save it again, still as `.tsv`. This makes me think it may be a line ending format issue, but I have used vim to check the endings in the input file, and they are consistently `\n`. What am I missing here?

Comment: I wouldn't give up on your line-ending theory quite yet.  Try checking the file (or the first few lines, at least) with `cat -t`.

Comment: With the sample and code provided, it works just fine.
The error you get is in `Col3` because you have to add `else if ( $i == "Col3") { $i = "NewCol3" } \`. between the Col2 and Col4 management.

Comment: @ingroxd - yeah, the error in there is expected - the code works fine, as I said in the post, but there is another issue.
@jas `cat -t` is showing `^M` as the line ending on my real input file. What's the significance of this? The real input file has not been on a Windows system though.

Comment: @tesolat: If you are using `gnu-awk` then use `awk -v RS='\r?\n' '...' file`

Comment: Okay, got there in the end. @anubhava fixed it directly (though was the `?` in the `RS`  in error?) and @jas pointed me to `^M`, which can be processed out using `sed`. Etiquette-wise, how to give thanks here? Answer it myself and give kudos to you both?

Comment: @tesolat the `?` is present so gawk will split the file on `\n`s whether preceded by `\r` or not. The downside to that is that then CSVs exported from Excel which have `\n` within fields will get mangled. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45420535/whats-the-most-robust-way-to-efficiently-parse-csv-using-awk.

Comment: Both links are very useful @EdMorton.  Neither showed in the searches I made prior to asking the question though :/  Hopefully setting the problem in this particular context (awk, column processing) may be helpful to someone else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently your input has line ending with `^M` or `\r`. You may use this `awk` with a custom regex in `RS` (this requires GNU `awk`):

```
awk -v RS='\r?\n' '...' file
```

`-v RS='\r?\n'` sets `RS` or record separator as **optional** `\r` followed by `\n`, thus allowing it to match lines ending with `\n` or `\r\n`.